# Redirecting with htaccess to nodejs app

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to run a small app I've wrote in nodejs on our server with [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). When I start my app like this:

```
forever app.js
```

In my folder `/home/me/apps/myapp/` and the app is listening on port 61000

What should be the content of my .htaccess file under `mydomain.me/myapp/`?

**Current `.htaccess` content** (not working):

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect a whole subdirectory:
RewriteRule ^myapp/(.*) http://localhost:61000/$1 [P]
```

Comment: you are trying to redirect request on your website to node server i think your node server will be directly accessible by mydomain.me:port on which node server is running

Comment: @user111111111 there is already a apache server running

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use Apache mod_proxy not mod_rewrite to run a Node.js app in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost :80>
    ServerName example.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /myapp>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:61000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:61000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you can't add a virtual host for your Node app you can try with htaccess and something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/myapp$ http://127.0.0.1:61000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/myapp/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:61000/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Where does this setting go? Also into the htaccess?

Comment: The nodejs app should only run in that specific subfolder. These settings look like they are for the whole server

Comment: In a virtual host conf usually in /etc/apache/sites-available

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this just with a htaccess file? There are some other projects running on this server. e.g. wordpress

Comment: Thanks @Michelem I will try the htaccess approach later on

Comment: I tried the htaccess approach but it does not work. I placed a index.html in the public folder and I still get it instead of the index my app should provide. Any hints where this might come from?

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 4):

I will answer my own question, even though I think Michelems answer is also right.

My initial .htaccess file works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myapp/(.*) http://localhost:61000/$1 [P]
```

The thing I did wrong was creating actually the folder `mydomain.de/myapp/` and put the .htaccess there. I have now the rewirte settings in my DocumentRoot/.htaccess, no public folder called `myapp` and it works fine.

Comment: Yes it was definetely that the problem.