# Node JS Application running on Apache CentOS6 - htaccess

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

We have searched and searched, but cannot for the life of us figure out how to edit our `.htaccess` file to allow our node.js application to run.

- Our root domain runs a wordpress website. We have built a custom API in Node to be deployed on `www.website.com/api`.
- We have `node` successfully installed on our centOS6. We are also able to run the node server successfully in the terminal by navigating to the `/api` folder and running `nohup node my_app.js &`. The logs confirm the server is running on port 51900.

Here's the problem. We know the node API is running, we just cant figure out how to see it. We're pretty sure we have to change our `.htaccess` file to redirect the `/api/` directory. Here is a copy/paste of our `.htaccess` file and what we have so far. Our redirects don't seem to work though.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/api$ http://127.0.0.1:51900/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:51900/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note: we did find [this similiar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386994/redirecting-with-htaccess-to-nodejs-app) but were unable to replicate the results of the poster

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386994/redirecting-with-htaccess-to-nodejs-app

Comment: Thanks @IanBrindley, but unfortunately as I commented above you, we were unable to replicate the success that user had. It's like our rewrite rule isn't recognized

Comment: Do your wordpress rules work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude your API URL from wordpress. Also in .htaccess you do not prepend a `/` in the rewriterule e.g `^/api`. There is no prepending slash in directory (htaccess) context. It should be `^api`. So that's also why your rule is not matching.  Try this and see if it helps.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:51900/$1 [P,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! THIS CODE WORKED (Almost!). We were getting a 'cannot get //' error after implementing your code. All we had to change was the location of the '/':

`RewriteRule ^api(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:51900/$1 [P,L]`

And now it works brilliantly! I edited your answer to reflect this change so others can benefit. Thanks again