# Apache htaccess configuration for nodejs apps fails

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have created a .htaccess file with the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule http://127.0.0.1:3034/ [P,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3034/$1 [P,L]
```

I have a nodejs app running at 127.0.0.1:3034 but whenever i visit the site with the htaccess already it doesnt load the nodejs app.
I have placed the .htaccess on the domain root folder.

I cannot edit the vhost files so the .htaccess file seems to be a better option when running nodejs apps in apache2
What am i missing out in my configiration

I have checked on [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386994/redirecting-with-htaccess-to-nodejs-app)

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your attempt:

1. the first `RewriteRule` does not make any sense
2. A `RewriteRule` operates on *relative* paths when implemented in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"), as opposed to *absolute* paths when implemented in the real http server's host configuration. Which is why the leading slash in your second `RewriteRule` prevented that rule from ever getting applied.

This is a slightly modified version of your approach:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3034/$1 [P]
```

For this to work you obviously need both the rewriting and the proxy module to be loaded and activated in the apache http server.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).