# Node.js Express only working for home page

Tags: node.js, express, plesk

I am running *Node.js* on *Plesk Obsidian 18.0.37*. I am not able to follow the link to page 2, only able to visit the home page. If I do follow the link or manually go to /page2, I'll get a 404 response. How could this be happening?

*app.js:*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.send("<h1>Home page</h1>" + 
                  '<br><a href="/page2">Page 2</a>');
});

app.get("/page2", (request, response) => {
    response.send("<h1>Page 2</h1>");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

---

**I also tried**:

serving a file, as suggested by **Aqua**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.send("<h1>Home page</h1>" +
                  '<br><a href="/page2">Page 2 with sendFile</a>');
});

app.get("/page2", (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile('page2.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

using a router, as suggested by **Harshit Rastogi**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.send("<h1>Home page with router</h1>" +
                  '<br><a href="/page2">Page 2</a>');
});

router.get("/page2", (request, response) => {
    response.send("<h1>Page 2 with router</h1>");
});

app.use(router);
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

I am still not able to follow the link to page 2, only able to visit the home page.

Comment: iv'e copied your `app.js` and all is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this by switching from Windows Server to a Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the declaration of your `app` variable to this:

```
const app = express.Router();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am not really good at express but try

```
app.get("/page2", (request, response) => {
    response.send("./link-to-html-file");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable nginx reverse proxy?

[How to install and enable nginx reverse proxy on a Plesk?](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213944825-How-to-install-and-enable-nginx-reverse-proxy-on-a-Plesk-for-Linux-server)

Every code that you posted worked for me.
Your error seem something related with port and/or proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your `app.js` file and all is working for me, macOS.

please see this post : https://talk.plesk.com/threads/webpages-are-no-longer-reachable-after-update-from-17-8-to-18-0.359321/

from what i understand this was fixed in the next version 18.0.38 or apply the fix they are working on for version 18.0.37.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the rewrite rules.

**Windows server:**

edit your **web.config** and set url rules are per your requirement,

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <rule name="page2">
           <match url="page2/*" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**Linux:**

Follow below post,

[Redirecting with htaccess to nodejs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386994/redirecting-with-htaccess-to-nodejs-app)